# Realtime User friends updates: new friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time

Unfortunately the facebook realtime api only informs about *something has changed* in the friends connection of the app's users.

What do I have to do to identify that *UserA* has just became friend with *UserX*?

Currently, anytime I receive a *UserA's friends have changed* notification from the facebook realtime api, I receive the whole `/UserA/friends.json`, paging throu the whole result to just identify what has been added since the last time.

While this works, it just feels like a lot of waste in compute-cycles and I like to know if there is a more elegant approach to this...

Answer (score 2):

That's the way it is designed and there is no "solution" for it.

> Note that this **does not include the actual data values** (either from
>   before or after the update). To obtain those, your app **can request**
>   them as normal, subject to the usual privacy restrictions. For data
>   that you have access to at any time, you may wish to query for that
>   data immediately following this callback so that it is ready for when
>   the user returns to your app.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

It makes a lot of sense, because Facebook is able to send you ALL UPDATES while not knowing if you have the appropriate permissions to get the new data, so a very easy way to do it in terms of privacy.

**If you have a valid user token** (in your db) you can retrieve the updated fields via Graph API / FQL and compare it with the data in your database. Without realtime API you need to pull data every x hours/days, which is even more waste of resources.

**If you don't have a valid user token** you can retrieve the updated fields via Graph API / FQL when the user comes back to your app and compare it with the data in your database. Without realtime API you always need to update/check the data when the user comes back.

Comment: Ok, I have valid user tokens. But how do I retrieve the "updated" fields? e.g. new friends since last date I checked. I think there is currently no way of querying friends ordered by add-date. So if a facebook user just got 1 new friend, and realtime api notifies about that, I still have to query all of his friends and compare against what I already have?

Comment: We're already making around 100k api-calls per day, mostly triggered by the realtime api. Just wanted to find out if there might be a way to reduce the cost of 'identifying new friends'.

Comment: Yep, there is no "created_date" field within the friend connection and no way to order the result by a _virtual_ "created_date" afaik.

Comment: Do you really have to save the user's friends? Can't you just get it whenever your application requires so. Maybe not all your application's features need it? When you need to verify friendship you can do that with an FQL query: (js) `"SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=" + uid + " AND uid2=" + targetId + ")"` That's how I'm doing it.